# is there any way to make an html button connected to the top

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make the CSS buttons connected to the top but I cant figure anything out
i made the code in w3 schools right [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQXXTKO89YOR)

the required result: [image]
and thats what im trying to do

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `connected` ?

Comment: youll see i edited the post

Comment: Do you want to fix the navigation bar on the top, or Will it scroll when the content flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can so first you need to remove that

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="notbutton">no text here ToTaLy No TeXt YAYAYAYAYAYAYAYA</button>
</div>
```

Than you add this

```
.btn-group {
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #282a35;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #303740;
}
```

and also you remove this line from the css of `.btn-group .button`

```
border-bottom: 4px solid #303740;
```

Than you will basically have the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-group {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #282a35;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #303740;
}

.btn-group .button {
  background-color: #282a35; /* Dark */
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}


.btn-group .button:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.btn-group .notbutton {
  background-color: #282a35; /* Dark */
  color: #282a35;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: cursor;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #303740;
     -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#1a1a1b;">

<form action="https://www.google.com">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button">Area</button>
  <button class="button">Area1</button>
  <button class="button">Area2</button>
</div>

<p style="clear:both"><br><br><br>the website</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but what about the left and right corners?

Comment: added `left: 0;` to lock it to the right to you want it to be touching the right corner too?

Comment: There you go edited the witdth of the div to make it 100% so its touching the right corner!

Comment: yes thats good but for some reason the text under the buttons don't show up

Comment: oh no i just need to add a few more <br>'s

Comment: Yeah fixed the snippet

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your code. The problem is that the example has the same issue that you are experiencing. If you open your code in full page view, you'll see that the `notbutton` element will move up to the top line. If you shrink your browser window, at some point the `notbutton` element jumps down to the next line.

Here's a solution that uses a wrapper `<nav>` element and `flexbox` for the `.btn-group` elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .btn-group .button {
      background-color: #282a35;
      /* Dark */
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #303740;
    }
    
    .btn-group .button:hover {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .btn-group .notbutton {
      background-color: #282a35;
      /* Dark */
      color: #282a35;
      padding: 0;             /* Remove padding from .notbutton */
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: cursor;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #303740;
      -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    nav,
    .btn-group {              /* make the nav and .btn-group flexbox */
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#1a1a1b;">

  <!-- Wrap your form and btn-group in another element such as <nav> -->
  <nav>
    <form action="https://www.google.com">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button">Area</button>
        <button class="button">Area1</button>
        <button class="button">Area2</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="notbutton">no text here ToTaLy No TeXt YAYAYAYAYAYAYAYA</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <p style="clear:both"><br>the website</p>

</body>

</html>
```